# crux sql if statement problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

Work on ms-server 2005.In my stored procedure i need to use if statement ,I already try to write but i fail ,**My syntax is bellow :**

```
Create Procedure TestProcedure
@Type int 

as


SELECT * INTO #temp1 FROM (
if @Type =0
select * from dbo.Manifest

else
select * from dbo.DischargePort

) as b
```

After execute the above syntax show me error message ,**Message** is

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure TestProcedure, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if'.
Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Procedure TestProcedure, Line 14
Line 14: Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

How to fix the problem,Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do both tables have the same structure? Are they `UNION` compatible? If not I think you will need to create a global temporary table using `EXEC(...)`

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT** Ok, so you can't actually insert into #temptable twice because the compiler does not recocgnize that it uses an if statement, the closest workaround was the following:

```
 IF @Type = 0
 BEGIN
     exec select * into #temp from dbo.Manifest
 END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
     select * into #temp from dbo.DischargePort
 END
```

**VERSION 2**

```
DECLARE @Type int = 0

IF @Type = 0     
exec ('select * into ##temp from dbo.Manifest')
ELSE 
exec ('select * into ##temp from dbo.DischargePort')

SELECT * FROM ##temp
```

And then remember to drop the table at the end

```
IF (SELECT object_id('TempDB..##temp')) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN    
    DROP TABLE ##temp
END
```

And then you would access ##temp like a normal table. Remember that if you want to add parameters to the dynamic sql use sp_exceutesql to avoid sql injection

Comment: Thanks for reply ,After execute your syntax show error message.  Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure TestProcedure, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TestProcedure, Line 22
There is already an object named '#temp' in the database.

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure TestProcedure, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TestProcedure, Line 22
There is already an object named '#temp' in the database.

Comment: There is already an object named '#temp' in the database.can you tell me how it's work.

Comment: Quickly having a look for you, 2 secs, it looks like sql prepare does not know that it will only create 1 of the 2 tables

Comment: yah!i want that,But above syntax fail to tell the sql

Comment: Does both tables share the same columns/schema?

Comment: try the change i've just made

Comment: no,but on above syntax both temp tables named are same.so show #temp object name already exist.Why not you run the query ,then reply.thanks

Comment: hmmm.......thanks for reply.I know how to execute sql statement on stored procedure ,but my scenario is different,i need to execute query as i described on above,Not like you.any way thanks for reply.

Comment: Ok, sorry couldn't help, unfortunately that is the only workaround I can see where you can define the same temp table twice in the same statement

Answer (score 0):

You remind to drop #temp at the end. Before table creation,you should check if #temp already exists.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL 
      DROP TABLE #temp
CREATE TABLE #temp (id int)
```

Comment: show same error message .There is already an object named '#temp' in the database.